# How to wait for Network response and then move(execute code) further after getting response in jetpack compose

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to achieve a functionality where my Complete profile page will check all the use cases for each field.

Every other field works fine with view-model and uses-cases but I am facing a problem while trying to check if username all ready exists or not in Firebase.

Use-Case for User Name.

```
class ValidateUserName() {

private var userAlways by Delegates.notNull<Boolean>()

@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
suspend fun execute(userName: String): ValidationResult {
    return ValidationResult(
        successful = false,
        errorMessage = "UserName Can't be empty"
    )
}

suspend fun query(userName: String): ValidationResult {
    val successful = getResult(userName)
    if (successful) {
        return ValidationResult(
            successful = false,
            errorMessage = "UserName already Exists \nPlease try another Username"
        )
    } else {
        return ValidationResult(
            successful = true
        )
    }
}

suspend fun getResult(userName: String): Boolean {
    var x = 0
    val readUserNameQuery = Firebase.firestore.collection("users")
    readUserNameQuery.whereEqualTo("username", userName).get().addOnSuccessListener {
        Log.e("RONALDO", "HERE I AM HERE :- " + it.toObjects<Any>().size)
        x = it.toObjects<Any>().size
    }.await()
    delay(2000L)
    return x > 0
}
```

}

ViewModel (Caller)

```
class CompleteProfileViewModel(
private val validateEmail : ValidateEmail = ValidateEmail(),
private val validateFirstName : ValidateFirstName = ValidateFirstName(),
private val validateLastName: ValidateLastName = ValidateLastName(),
private val validateUserName: ValidateUserName = ValidateUserName()
```

) : ViewModel() {
var state by mutableStateOf(CompleteProfileState())

```
private val validationEventChannel = Channel<ValidationEvent>()
val validationEvents = validationEventChannel.receiveAsFlow()

fun onEvent(event: CompleteProfileEvent ){
    when(event){
        is CompleteProfileEvent.EmailChanged -> {
            state = state.copy(email = event.email)
        // the way to change state is to create(copy) whole new object
        }
        is CompleteProfileEvent.FirstNameChanged -> {
            state = state.copy(firstName = event.firstName)
        }
        is CompleteProfileEvent.LastNameChanged -> {
            state = state.copy(lastName = event.lastName)
        }
        is CompleteProfileEvent.UserNameChanged -> {
            state = state.copy(userName = event.userName)
        }
        is CompleteProfileEvent.Submit -> {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                submitData()
            }
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun submitData() {

    val userNameResult = if (state.userName.isNotBlank()){
        validateUserName.query(state.userName)
    }else{
        validateUserName.execute(state.userName)
    }
    val emailResult = validateEmail.execute(state.email)
    val firstNameResult = validateFirstName.execute(state.firstName)
    val lastNameResult = validateLastName.execute(state.lastName)
    val hasError = listOf(
        userNameResult,
        emailResult,
        firstNameResult,
        lastNameResult
    ).any{
        !it.successful
    }
    if (hasError){
        state = state.copy(
            emailError = emailResult.errorMessage,
            firstNameError = firstNameResult.errorMessage,
            lastNameError = lastNameResult.errorMessage,
            userNameError = userNameResult.errorMessage
        )
        return
    }
    viewModelScope.launch {
        validationEventChannel.send(ValidationEvent.Success)
    }
}
sealed class ValidationEvent{
    object Success : ValidationEvent()
}
```

}

Sorry for this code is not formatted Correctly

I just want to wait for my Firebase response before moving further. await() is not working in my case.
suspend fun getResult(userName: String): Boolean() is returning false and then getting the response.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code lies in the following lines of code:

```
readUserNameQuery.whereEqualTo("username", userName).get().addOnSuccessListener {
    Log.e("RONALDO", "HERE I AM HERE :- " + it.toObjects<Any>().size)
    x = it.toObjects<Any>().size
}.await()
```

Firebase API is asynchronous. Any code that needs data from the database needs to be inside the `onSuccess()` method, or be called from there. That being said, returning a value from an asynchronous operation as a result of a method doesn't provide the expected result.

> await() is not working in my case.

It's because you're calling `await()` after attaching the listener. If you want to wait for the operation to complete, then you should call `await()` right after calling `get()`. It's one or the other:

```
val size = readUserNameQuery.whereEqualTo("username", userName).get().await().toObjects<Any>().size
Log.e("RONALDO", "HERE I AM HERE :- " + size)
```